# Using Getopt::Long to drive a system command on linux

Tags: php, perl, getopt-long

I am trying to execute a php script with arguments, using the following perl driver:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Cwd;

my %args = ();

GetOptions(
            \%args,           "NUM_AGENTS|a=s",
            "HOST_NAME|h=s",  "TIME_STAGGER|t=s",
            "USER_NAME|un=s", "USER_PASS|pw=s",
            "TARGET_PAGE|p=s"
) or die "Unknown parameter!\n";

my $i         = 0;
my $startTime = time;

my $pwd = getcwd();

my $logdir = "$pwd/load-logs";

mkdir $logdir
  or die "Cannot mkdir $logdir: $!"
  unless -d $logdir;
chmod 0755, $logdir or die "Cannot chmod 0755 $logdir: $!";

my $startTimeTemp = $args{NUM_AGENTS} + $startTime;
my $startTime2    = $startTimeTemp + 10;

mkdir( "$logdir/$startTime2", 0777 )
  or die "Cannot mkdir $logdir/$startTime2: $!"
  unless -d "$logdir/$startTime2";

my $random_number = rand() * 10;
my $execDelay =
  ( $random_number % $args{TIME_STAGGER} ) * ( ( $random_number % 100 ) );
my $procStartTime = $startTime2 + $execDelay;

my $reqlogfile  = "$logdir/$startTime2/req.log";
my $resplogfile = "$logdir/$startTime2/resp.log";

print "NUM_AGENTS: " . "$args{NUM_AGENTS}\n";
print "HOST_NAME: " . "$args{HOST_NAME}\n";
print "procStartTime: " . "$procStartTime\n";
print "i: " . "$i\n";
print "TARGET_PAGE: " . "$args{TARGET_PAGE}\n";
print "resplogfile: " . "$resplogfile\n";
print "USER_NAME: " . "$args{USER_NAME}\n";
print "USER_PASS: " . "$args{USER_PASS}\n";
print "execDelay: " . "$execDelay\n";
print "COMMON_SID: " . "$args{COMMON_SID}\n";

while ( $args{NUM_AGENTS} > $i ) {
    $i++;
    print "count: " . "$i\n";

    my $argString =
"'$args{NUM_AGENTS}' '$args{HOST_NAME}' '$procStartTime' '$i' '$args{TARGET_PAGE}' 'resplogfile' '$reqlogfile' '$args{USER_NAME}' '$args{USER_PASS}' '$execDelay' '$args{COMMON_SID}'";

    system("php loadAgent_curl.php $argString") == 0 or die "failed to execute: $!";

    sleep 1;

    #system("ls");
}
```

but it seems, that something is wrong with :

```
system("php loadAgent_curl.php $argString")
```

since the ls system commands runs fine, but the php command with arguments does not

The Command Line arguments ot this perl script can be:

-a 10 -h ktest.test.net -t 5 -un admin -pw adminpassword -p "acViewer/index.html?StartDate=20090926040000&EndDate=20111220235959"

Comment: What's the full path to the `php` binary?  Is it in the PATH?  Why not try fully qualifying it?

Comment: Is the PHP script running or not. Try breaking problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the type of error message you're getting. Was it something like `Cannot find "php"` or something else.

You might be having trouble with quotes. Here's a few recommendations:

- Use `qq()` instead of quotation marks. That'll make things a bit cleaner.
- Build the command into a variable called `$command` which you can print out in case you have errors. That might help you understand where you maybe having a problem.
- Set a variable called `$error` when executing `system`, and then check that variable. It's a lot clearer than the backwards style of `and/or` stuff that you have to do on failure and success, and it's a lot easier to maintain.

Example:

```
my $argString = qq("$args{NUM_AGENTS}" "$args{HOST_NAME}" ) 
    . qq( "$procStartTime" "$i" "$args{TARGET_PAGE}" "resplogfile" )
    . qq("$reqlogfile" "$args{USER_NAME}" "$args{USER_PASS}" )
    . qq("$execDelay" "$args{COMMON_SID}");

my $command = qq(php loadAgent_curl.php $argString);

my $error = system qq($command);
if ($error) {
    die qq(ERROR: Failed to execute "$command"\n\n$!);
}
```

At least this way, you can see what command failed, and get a better idea why it might not have executed.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike most other Perl commands, `system` returns 0 on "success" and non-zero on "failure". So the typical idiom is

```
system $command and die ...
```

instead of

```
system $command or die ...
```

**Update**: the OP did get this part right -- `system(...)==0 or die ...` is also a perfectly fine way to do error checking on the `system` command.

---

There also might be some funky quoting in the exact command you are passing to the `system` command. For a task like this, it is often best to bypass the shell and use the LIST form of `system` to pass the command directly to the OS. Maybe something like:

```
my @argList = ($args{NUM_AGENTS}, $args{HOST_NAME}, $procStartTime, $i,
               $args{TARGET_PAGE}, 'resplogfile', $reqlogfile, $args{USER_NAME},
               $execDelay, $args{COMMON_SID});
system("php", "loadAgent_curl.php", @argList) and die "failed to execute: $!";
```

(and also make sure `php` is in your `$PATH` [or specify the complete path to `php`] and `loadAgent_curl.php` is in the current directory).

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP - GetOptionKit:

http://c9s.blogspot.com/2011/11/php-getoptionkit.html

synopsis

```
use GetOptionKit\GetOptionKit;

$getopt = new GetOptionKit;
$spec = $getopt->add( 'f|foo:' , 'option require value' );  # returns spec object.

$getopt->add( 'b|bar+' , 'option with multiple value' );
$getopt->add( 'z|zoo?' , 'option with optional value' );

$getopt->add( 'f|foo:=i' , 'option require value, with integer type' );
$getopt->add( 'f|foo:=s' , 'option require value, with string type' );
```